# What is the best way to explain the findings in Jmeter to a customer?

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, test-management, jmeter-plugins, team-management

Yes, I know a simple question at first glance, but on the second it leaves you perplexed.

**Details:**

One of our customers got a complete setup from us, and that was Jmeter and an integration into a Jenkins CI/CD pipeline, with an integration into Jira and Xray.

So far so good. We created several profiles for the customer, with different profiles and customer. Have also made a corresponding run at the customer. Everything works and there are also corresponding results to the desired specifications.

Created a meaningful Jmeter report and then handed it over to the customer.

The problem is that apparently the team which we have delivered the report, can not do anything with the reports of Jmeter? The same goes for the product owner. And they probably expect the solution to the problem accordingly?

And this makes us absolutely perplexed, because on the one hand the reports of Jmeter should be understandable for teams working with it, and yet clearly show where the problems are.

**Questions:**

- Is it a communication problem, or how can I as a tester address the
  team so that the report is easier and understandable?
- How can we possibly make the Jmeter report even better and, above
  all, simpler? What possibilities do you see to proceed here?

**Possibilities:**

- Use monitoring tools that analyze the findings in the CI/CD pipelines
  and provide corresponding solution proposals?
- Maybe the Jmeter dashboard would be something

**Examples:**

I have been running some load tests against APIs using JMeter, the results are below:

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of such a finding?

Comment: Added a Example. Basically we have checked a store system at a customer on the one hand the APIs and on the other hand single pages and URls which clearly have load problems.

Answer (score 2):

This report is not really a "meaningful Jmeter report" for non techies. Either have someone technical enough interpreting the report or analyze and explain what the problem is in a clear and actionable way, preferably automatically. A PM will understand "the connection time in scenario B is much larger compared to scenario A" but not a vague table.